# Ubuntu Texlive install missing packages when compiling document

Tags: packages, texlive, texlive-2017, missing

I have a minimal Texlive vanilla installation based on the [tug.org guide](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). I only installed

```
a [X] Essential programs and files
```

and

```
D [X] LaTeX fundamental packages
```

using the command line config and finally set the path variables.

Now I downloaded a `.tex` file that includes a lot of packages that I have obviously not installed.

Compiling causes many of the typical `not found` error:

```
$ pdflatex main.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))

! LaTeX Error: File `somepackagename.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: <-- would be awesome to fetch missing packes from url
```

On windows I had this awesome functionality (can't determine if shipped by MikTex or the Texworks editor) where I got asked if I want to install this package (and do the same for all following missing packages).

Just clicking yes caused the program to fetch the package, install it and continue with compilation.

How is this possible in linux? Can I auto-configure the `tlmgr` program to do that?

Note: I don't want to install any `apt` packages or big collections but only those missing packages at compiletime.

Comment: You can try this package: `https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texliveonfly` which is also in TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The feature you refer to is supported by MikTeX specifically. TeX Live does not offer it on any platform - Windows, OS X, Linux, BSD or anything else.